# running an AngularJS app in general

Tags: angularjs

I am taking baby steps with AngularJS. I am a bit confused about requiring a webserver to run  an AngularJS sample or demo. The reason is for study purpose I have downloaded running examples and demos, but not having any luck with it. A very simple demo of displaying a name is not working for me. Do I have to do anything specific to get a simple app running. I feel very weird asking my doubt requing  a webserver as AngularJS is a client side Framework. Nevertheless, hoping someone can throw some light on this.
Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Firefox, then you don't need any server to have your basic app running. If you use Chrome, then for security reasons it doesn't like file-access to librairies. Librairies must be serve in another way. So you can have the hello-world AngularJS working by opening the classic index.html with Firefox, so that you don't have to start any web server.

Here is a sample application with explanations in the README :

https://github.com/davidb583/white-angularjs-app

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you don't need a webserver to run AngularJS application since it is client-side framework.